# How to fix the array, identifier, and initializer errors?

Tags: c

Can anyone help fix this code? It has 4 errors

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

#define MAX 9

typedef struct
{
    char names[10];
    int votes;
}
candidate;

candidate candidates[MAX];

int candidate_count;


bool vote(char names[]);
void winner(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: Plurality [Cnadidate...]\n");
        return 1;
    }
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if(candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("The maximum number of candidates are %d\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    //
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].names = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }
     int voter_count;
     printf("Enter the number of voters: \n");
     scanf("%d", &voter_count);

     for(int j = 0; j < voter_count; j++)
     {
         printf("Vote: \n");
         scanf("%s", names[j]);
     }
     if(!vote(names))
     {
         printf("Invalid");
     }

     winner();
}

bool vote(char name[])
{
    bool exist = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        //check if the typed in name is in the list of candidates
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].names) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes ++;
            exist = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    return exist;
}

void winner(void)
{
    int most = candidates[0].votes;
    char winner[10] = candidates[0].names;
    for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (most < candidates[i].votes)
        {
            most = candidates[i].votes;
            winner = candidates[i].names;
        }
    }

    //printf("%d", most);
    printf("%s\n", winner);
    return;
}
```

**ERRORS:**

```
plurality.c:39:29: error: array type 'char [10]' is not assignable
        candidates[i].names = argv[i + 1];
        ~~~~~~~ ^
plurality.c:49:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'names'
         scanf("%s", names[j]);
                     ^
plurality.c:51:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'names'
     if(!vote(names))
             ^
plurality.c:81:10: error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
    char winner[10] = candidates[0].names;
         ^
4 errors generated.
```

Comment: Please do not tag C++ if your code is pure C

Comment: you need to break this question up into multiple questions. focus on one bug at a time. its hard to help you with a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign arrays in C or C++, for arrays representing C strings you can use the function `strcpy` instead

```
strcpy(candidates[i].names, argv[i + 1]);
```

and

```
strcpy(winner, candidates[i].names);
```

Comment: @VibhakGolchha I'm sure, you have lots of errors, I only pointed out the most obvious one.

Comment: @VibhakGolchha Bugs gang up on you and make the difficulty of resolving them grow rapidly. The best way to make sure you only deal with small amounts of errors at a time is to write small amounts of code at a time. Write a few lines, a small function at the most, then stop, compile, and test. Do not proceed unless the program behaves exactly as expected. As you get more experienced, you will be able to write larger and larger amounts of code in a shot because you just won't make as many mistakes. Even the best programmers stop and test frequently.

Answer (score 0):

your code is incomprehensible , for example what are you doing in this part? where have you declared "names" in this case ?!!

```
  for(int j = 0; j < voter_count; j++)
   {
     printf("Vote: \n");
     scanf("%s", names[j]);
  }
```